# Connect mongo DB with dialogflow CX through the platform, not code

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, webhooks, agent, dialogflow-cx

I need some help because I'm searching for information but I can´t find what i'm searching for. I'm trying to connect dialogflow CX with Mongo DB, Dialogflow should return the info I'm asking from the database, but I need to do this since dialogflow cx platform, not code. I already have an API with get method, which is my webhook, but I don´t know what else to do. So, please if anyone know how I can do this i will be very grateful if you can explain it to me.

I was trying to do it through data store from google but it was unsucessful and I already try through my webhook but it doesn't work

Comment: You should be using a Flexible Webhook to get the data out of your web API https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook#flexible

What is the part you're having problem with? Invoking the API or the handling of the return values?